# Import and images within an Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to set up an excel document that would allow me to import an image and either have it contained within the cell or turn it into a link that one can open to view the image. I floated the idea of just adding a hyperlink to the local file, but since this document will be shared, the image will have to actually be imported directly into the document. I'm sure I'm grasping at straws here, but any help would be amazing.

I'm using Excel 2019. Thanks a ton!

Comment: What do you mean by link? Click it and jump to the picture? Or click and picture would open in another tool?

Comment: Would you like to get the images from any web site or from the local drive ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could insert the picture as an object.

Go to Insert > Text group > Object > Create from File > Browse to this image and insert it.

Then you may adjuest the icon in a cell.

[image]

If you need to open it, please double click the icon to have a check.